# How do i run different scripts parallely using shell

Tags: scripts

I have script1,script2,script3

I have to execute all the three at same time using one shell script.Not one after the other.How do I do that?

Comment: Is it a school task?

Comment: no why did you ask that?..I want to do a Asynchornous execution of muiple scripts

Comment: There are a number of stackexchange sites that are almost all school task related questions, why should computer science be any different than the other sciences?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by

```
script1&script2&script3
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not really multi threading afaik however did you try:

```
    script1 &
    script2 &
    script3 &
    wait
```

The `wait` command will wait for all the backgrounded jobs to finish.